# How to get rid of the border spacing using Graphviz HTML tables?

Tags: html, graphviz, html-table, dot

```
<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="left">d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width="50">ct</td>
        <td align="left">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">wt</td>
        <td align="left">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The Graphviz output:

[image]

The expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `cellspacing="0"` to your `table` tag

---

Also take a look at this: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html

Comment: It was stupid of me not trying to do it myself. I assumed it is not supported since it is not mentioned in the documentation, http://www.graphviz.org/content/node-shapes.

Comment: Double fail. It is documented. Thank you.

Comment: This happens even the best :)